# Will this xbox 360 receiver work on OS X?

Tags: macos, xbox360, osx-yosemite

Will the following XBOX 360 controller receiver work on OS X 10?

http://www.ebay.com/itm/PC-Wireless-Controller-Gaming-Receiver-For-MICROSOFT-XBOX-360-White-/390814020442?pt=US_Other_Video_Game_Accessories&hash=item5afe54b35a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to install [Tattiebogle 0.11](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver#toc1), take a look at [this instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-an-Xbox-360-Controller-on-OS-X-wired-wirele/?ALLSTEPS) - good luck! This information is supplied without liability :)

Answer (score 1):

I have that dongle working on OSX Yosemite right now. I've used it since Lion. It requires a 3rd party download driver (linked below). It's pretty much plug and play once you have the driver.

http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver